# getting count in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
boss_id    employee_id      designation        
 -1           100              CEO
100           39               Manager 
100          4567              Manager
100          9843              Manager
39            47               entry level
39            45               entry level
4567          8                entry level
9843          9                entry level
```

In this boss_id gives the boss of the employee. Designation is for the employee. 
I want to find how many people each person manages in total.

For instance, since CEO is the ultimate person, he should be managing all 7 people in this dataframe. Managers manage just the entry level. For instance, employee 39 who is a manager manages 2 people in this dataframe. Finally, the entry levels don't manage anyone, so their count should be 0.

I want a dataframe like this:

```
boss_id    employee_id      designation              count
 -1           100              CEO                     7
100           39               Manager                 2
100          4567              Manager                 1
100          9843              Manager                 1
39            47               entry level             0
39            45               entry level             0
4567          8                entry level             0
9843          9                entry level             0
```

I can't get my head around this and any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot give you proper Dataframe equation, but logic should be something like count(employee_ID) where boss_id = selectedItem.employee_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively call employee_ids and find their counts

```
    def findCount(employee_id):
        if df.loc[df['employee_id'] == employee_id]['designation'].as_matrix()[0] == 'd':
            return 0
        eIds = df.loc[df['boss_id']==employee_id]['employee_id'].as_matrix()  
        cnt = 0
        for eid in eIds:
            cnt += (findCount(eid) + 1)
        return cnt

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cnt = findCount(row['employee_id'])
        df.loc[index, 'count'] = cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `groups = df.groupby([boss_id])`

go to the group's and get the count.

```
`for boss_id, group in groups:
     count = len(group)`
```